# how do I configure the dependency among my local jars with maven?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have configured a local repository and have some jars on it. Through the pom file, I used them but when I execute the mvn package phase, I'm seeing...

[WARNING] The POM for p-unit:p-unit:jar:0.15.319 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for p-unit:p-unit-extension:jar:0.15.319 is missing, no dependency information available

I guess that maven didn't found the jars in the maven repo, so then it uses my local repo because the package phase ends fine.. but **I would like to configure the dependency among my local jars** (the p-unit-extension.jar depends on the p-unit.jar). How can I configure this in maven?

this is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.test</groupId>
 <artifactId>perf-test</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>punit-test</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

 <repositories>
<repository>
    <id>snapshots</id>
    <url>file:///D:/Users/jmann/.m2/local</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
</repository>

 </repositories>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>      
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>p-unit</groupId>
  <artifactId>p-unit</artifactId>      
  <version>0.15.319</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>p-unit</groupId>
  <artifactId>p-unit-extension</artifactId>      
  <version>0.15.319</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency> 
</dependencies>
</project>
```

I would like to put only the p-unit-extension dependency so that maven downloads the p-unit jar automatically. Any error in my pom, please tell me.

this is my settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:schemaLocation="maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">; 
  <localRepository>D:/Users/jmann/.m2/local</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <activeProfiles/>
  <pluginGroups/>
</settings>
```

Comment: How does your settings.xml file look like?

Comment: How did you add things to the local repository? Also, `0.15.319` looks like a release artifact (no `-SNAPSHOT`) while your repo config appears to suggest a snapshot repo.

Comment: now, I know that there are webapps for local repositories.. I'll try Artifactory but I still don't know how to configure the dependencies between local artifacts